# How to use rsfs (mathscript) fonts in usual commercial applications?

Tags: fonts

The question is in the title. I am working on a geometry book, and diagrams are made with Illustrator.

Comment: the rsfs fonts are type 1 fonts and illustrator not longer supports type1 so you can't use them there. Choose some other open type math font.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found on ctan.org the files rsfs10.pfb, rsfs7.pfb and rsfs5.pfb which in principle contain the outlines and metrics of the rsfs fonts, but the Mac Font Book doesn't see them, and neither do the Adobe applications. Does the Font Book also ignore type 1 fonts (pfb fonts are type 1)? Is this the reason why some font names appear in gray on the Font Book? But the Font Book would not even register rsfs10.pfb and the like. Is it safe to use pfb to ttf free converters on the web?